# Why does ABPeoplePicker cause lots of warnings in the console?

Tags: swift, macos, abaddressbook, peoplepicker

In a brand new Swift app for OSX I dropped an `ABPeoplePickerView` in the window. Apart from importing AddressBook and creating an outlet for the peoplepicker, I added no code. On running the app (successfully - the picker works fine), the console filled up with about 30 warnings like this one :

AddressBookTest2[47632:12458347] [error] warning: dynamic accessors failed to find @property implementation for 'uniqueId' for entity ABCDInfo while resolving selector 'uniqueId' on class 'ABCDInfo'.  Did you remember to declare it @dynamic or @synthesized in the @implementation ?

Should I be worrying? Or have I missed something?

Comment: Returning after a couple of years I see the problem is not ABPeoplePicker, but with AddressBook itself. Even the single line `let ab = ABAddressBook.shared()` in an otherwise empty app causes the error. I'm surprised this has not been mentioned elsewhere; it almost merits a separate question. Has no-one come up against this?